# How to copy blob data from one storage acc in one subscription to other storage acc in other subscription using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have data in one storage acc in dev subscription. I need to move the data to other storage acc in other  subscription.

Is there any way to do this by ADF by copy activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have multiple paths that you want to copy from Dev to Prod:

1. create a linked service to dev blob and prod blob
2. create dynamic datasets:
   a) source dataset with a parameterized path (mapping to dev)
   b) sink dataset with parameterized path(mapping to prod)
3. use a lookup activity to get the list of all paths/containers
4. pass it to a for each activity and within for each activity use Copy activity
   [image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#recursive-and-copybehavior-examples

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create one linked Service pointing to Storage Account in DEV Subscription and then another linked Service pointing to Storage Account in Other Subscription. Once the connections are established, you should be able to use a Copy Activity using source dataset (pointing to DEV Subscription Linked Service) and sink Dataset (pointing to Other Subscription Linked Service)

Comment: How to move all the containers like i want same containers in deva and prod too